# How to open the last page from which user terminated the app in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am noob in flutter and i have made the app of about 6-8 pages.All i want is to continue from last screen from which the user leave or terminated the app completely.

Also is it possible using mobx??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can persist the route name every time you open a new route then look for the last rout every time you open the app:

```dart
String lastRouteKey = 'last_route';

void main() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String lastRoute = preferences.getString(lastRouteKey);
  runApp(MyApp(lastRoute));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String lastRoute;

  MyApp(this.lastRoute);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool hasLastRoute = getWidgetByRouteName(lastRoute) != null;

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Foo(),
      initialRoute: hasLastRoute ? lastRoute : '/',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings route) {
        persistLastRoute(route.name);
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => getWidgetByRouteName(route.name),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget getWidgetByRouteName(String routeName) {
    switch (routeName) {
      case '/': return MainWidget();
      // Put all your routes here.
      default: return null;
    }
  }

  void persistLastRoute(String routeName) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.setString(lastRouteKey, routeName);
  }
}
```

Note that this is not 100% precise, since persisting is asynchronous and the user may close the app before it finishes. However, it usually happens really fast and should work almost all the times.

Comment: hey Hugo, it's you again!  We wrote similar answer within the same few minutes!

Comment: Hi there.You gotta be faster! :)

Comment: thanks allot.is there any way i can save the whole stack?

Comment: What do you mean by the whole stack? Do you want to save the whole history of routes?

Comment: Yes,means stack of all the pages opened before.

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare a global variable gv.strCurPage.
2. In the initstate of each page, set gv.strCurPage equal to current page name, e.g. 'page3'.  Then, store this value into SharePreferences.
3. At the very beginning of main() inside main.dart, retrieve that value from SharePreference, store it in gv.strCurPage, if this value is empty, set gv.strCurPage = 'page1'.
4. In runApp(), set the first page, using a switch statement, according to the value of gv.strCurPage.

i.e.  when user open the app for the first time, the first page is page1.  Then, suppose the user naviagate to page5, a value 'page5' will be stored in sharepreference, and retrieved next time the user open the app. so 'page5' will become the first page of the app in next open.

Comment: thanks I got it . is there any way to store the whole stack of screens??

Comment: suppose user visit page1, then page2, then page3, then page2 again.  which one of the following would you like to store?  Option (a): page1, page2, page3, page2.   Option (b): page1, page2, page3.   Option (c): page1, page3, page2.

Comment: after choosing the above options, pls also tell me, e.g. when the user open the app again, would you like the whole stack of screens for the second run: option(1) override the first run?    or Option (2): add to the end of first run?

Comment: choose either a,b,c  AND choose either 1 or 2, then I can give you advice on how to save the whole stacks.

Comment: page1=>page2 only. page 3 will gonna pop out of the stack.And also it overrides the first run.Thanks though.

Comment: seriously?  you mean after user navigate N Pages, you only keep the first one and the last one?

Comment: any way, since the Xth run overrides the (X-1)th run, the no. of stacks should be limited, you can put these page names in an array (i.e. a List <String>), then use json_encode to format this list to a string and save it using SharePreference. then whenever you retrieve this steing, use json_decode to convert this string back to a List<String>. In the future, if you need to store infinte no.of records locally inside the mobile phone, you should use sqflite instead of sharepreference